# windows 10 vs windows server 2016 as jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, windows

The builds are running locally in my Windows 10 OS successfully. Can I run the same builds in Jenkins slave with Windows Server 2016? Will there be any issues during the build or should I go for Windows 10 OS for the slave setup?

Comment: What issues are you anticipating? Answering your question is difficult without knowing the application you’re building.

Comment: Using embedded software to build using cmake and MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you do something distro-specific (i.e. something which depends on the specific version of Windows) there should be no issues.